# Playwright - API testing - connection timeout error - possible reason behind corporate proxy

Tags: proxy, playwright, http-proxy, connection-timeout

I tried to use [this api tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umHMs56_YWA&list=PL-hNDoK1-od_HpjnFwFZnjKpIs_D-lEpn&index=2) to call a webservice from behind our proxy.

But i get

> ```
> Error: apiRequestContext.get: Connection timeout
> Call log:
>   - → GET https://reqres.in/api/users/2
>   -   user-agent: Playwright/1.40.1 (x64; windows 10.0) node/18.7
>   -   accept: */*
>   -   accept-encoding: gzip,deflate,br
> ```

If i open [reqres.in/api/users/2](https://reqres.in/api/users/2) in a browser it works as expected. If i run `npm run tests:chrome` the demo test `example.spec.ts` that opens [playwright.dev](https://playwright.dev) works as well.

My test `api.spec.ts` has these lines

```js
import {test, expect} from '@playwright/test'
import { assert } from 'console'
import exp from 'constants'

test.describe.parallel("Api testing", () => {
    const baseURL = "https://reqres.in/api"
    test("Simple API 1", async ({request}) => {
        const response = await request.get( "https://reqres.in/api/users/2")
        // const response = await request.get( `${baseURL}/users/2`)
        expect(response.status()).toBe(200)
    })
})
```

And my `api.config.ts` has these lines

```js
import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';
import exp from 'constants';
import { userInfo } from 'os';

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
    timeout: 60000,
    retries: 0,
    testDir: 'tests/api',
    use: {
        headless: false, viewport: {width: 1280, height: 720},
        actionTimeout: 10000, ignoreHTTPSErrors: true, video: 'off', screenshot: 'off'
    },
    projects: [ { name: 'Chromium', use: { browserName: 'chromium'}, } ]
}

export default config
```

And my `package.json` has these lines

```json
{
  "name": "api-24-01", "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Automated Software testing with Playwright",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "tests:chrome" : "playwright test --config=playwright.config.ts --project=Chromium",
    "tests:api" : "playwright test --config=api.config.ts --project=Chromium"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.40.1",
    "@types/node": "^20.10.8"
  }
}
```

The current [guide on api testing](https://playwright.dev/docs/api-testing) has no explanation if any additional actions or configurations must be done behind a corporate proxy that requires authentication.

### Question

What do i have to do / to configure to use Playwright API testing behind a corporate proxy that requires authentication?

Comment: Your code looks good and i have tried on my machine it works perfectly fine. May be your company does not allow to use it. You can use below API for your practice. It has authorization as bearer token which need to add in your config file.  You can get Authorization token by signing up to application.

https://gorest.co.in/

Comment: Hello Ketan i believe that the access to the URI is not blocked since i can access it with the browser. What is probably missing is to pass proxy authentication credentials from playwright to the proxy that every reqeust and response is routed over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The playwright team added a section for **How to use a proxy for api testing** to the [API testing guide](https://playwright.dev/docs/api-testing).

To use [api](/questions/tagged/api) [testing](/questions/tagged/testing) with [playwright](/questions/tagged/playwright) the config file `playwright.config.ts` must have a configuration for your `proxy : {}` like in this example

```js
import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';
import exp from 'constants';
import { userInfo } from 'os';

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
    timeout: 60000,
    retries: 0,
    testDir: 'tests/api',
    use: {
        headless: true,
        viewport: {width: 1280, height: 720},
        actionTimeout: 10000,
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        video: 'off',
        screenshot: 'off',
        proxy: {
            server: 'http://<your-proxy-server>:<port>',
            username: '<your-user>',
            password: '<your-pass>'
        },
    },
    projects: [
        {
            name: 'Chromium',
            use: { browserName: 'chromium'},
        }
    ]
}

export default config
```

This solved the connection timeout problem.